# Is it possible to define the functions on a domain without explicitly stating the rule to evaluate it?

Tags: functions

Usually when we are given functions, it is almost second nature on how to evaluate it $f(x)=x^2$, you take it as taking a number and squaring. This is under the assumption that we are talking about a map from the real numbers to the real numbers.

Suppose we instead define the map from the "set of fruits" to set of vegetables", clearly $f(\text{pineapple})$ is not something that makes sense to compute. Would the map still be a function? (which is undefined everywhere of course).(*)

Here is a more math example of the idea I am trying to understand, consider $f=\ln(x)$ defined from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , it is not clear on how to extend the computation rule of the above object from the one of the standard definition of $\ln(x)$ from $R^{+} \to R$ for evaluating with negative and zero values.

Would it still make sense to call the above two examples functions? In essence, I want to ask if it makes sense to call a relation between sets a function, if the exact prescription for how objects between sets are related is defined.

[Maybe related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295152/can-you-define-non-effectively-calculable-function-in-constructive-mathematics)

---

*: To clarify, I mean a specific set of fruits, no ambguity involved. It could be {apple,banana, grapes} for instance.

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is a function with domain the set of all postive real numbers and range R

Comment: There are uncomputable functions, so there need not be a formula how to calculate the value. Important is that it is clearly defined.

Comment: If we say, "Let $f$ be a function from the set of fruits to the set of vegetables," the problem isn't so much that we don't know how to compute $f$, but that we're not sure what the set of fruits is.  Is "apple" a member of the set, or should it be "delicious apple"?  Or maybe "yellow delicious apple".  Is "blueberry" a fruit, or do we have "wild blueberry" and "cultivated blueberry"?  There are similar problems with the set of vegetables, of course. 
 However, if we said "Let $f$ be a function from *a* set of fruits to *a* set of vegetables", I don't think there's any problem.

Comment: Oh my god, this is one of the best comments that I have ever read. I actually am not even going to edit the question because I want the comment to stay in context. @Saulspatz

Comment: An important point that is almost never mentioned when talking about "functions". A "function" is a special kind of mapping between two sets. It is special in that it cannot map an item in the domain to more than one item in the codomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Set Theory a function IS its graph, so a function $F$ from $B$ to $C$ is a subset of $B\times C$ such that $\forall b\in B\,\exists !\,c\in C\,(\,(b,c)\in F).$

We can speak of a function from $B$ to $C,$ or speak of the set of all functions from $B$ to $C,$ without needing to refer to any formulas for calculating functions.

It is often desirable to "extend" a function $F:B\to C$ to a function $F'$ on a domain $B'\supsetneq B,$ that is, $F'(b)=F(b)$ whenever $b\in B,$ but for convenience the same symbol $F$ is often used for $F',$ even though $F$ and $F'$ are different things.

Comment: Ok on rereading, what exactly do you mean by graph? Do you mean the visualization we do in the cartesian plane with the curves and stuff? that seems a little 'restraining' because I think so there must be other ways to visualize functions as well

Comment: Just to confirm, this does imply the fruit function is still a function right? We've extended to a new domain but we haven't given the rule to evaluate the function in the new domain

Comment: There are many useful intuitive ways to "picture" a function. But we also need a precise $definition$ of "function". The graph in the Cartesian plane IS the function.... You can say there $exists$ a function whose domain  is the set F of fruits, provided that such a set F exists. It may be that F exists, regardless of whether we are sure about its members.  Much of math is general statements. E.g. : Theorem (Euclid): There is no largest prime number. His classic proof does not provide a formula for finding whether any $n\in\Bbb N$ is prime or not.